# Type error while trying to create a Histogram without using the standard functions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to create a function that returns an array that counts numbers in bins of 2, but I keep getting a type error. Please can someone help?

The array math_scores is a bunch of numbers with decimals. Example [60.3, 20.1, 30.9 etc..]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from helper import plotHisto
data = np.loadtxt('math_scores.txt')
def buildHisto(data) :
    hist =  20 * [0]
    for d in data :
        hist[d // 2] += 1
        print(hist)
print(buildHisto(data))
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64
```

Comment: Apparently, `type(np.float64(x) // y) == float`.  You can force it to be an `int` with `hist[int(d // 2)] += 1`.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped!